# Cumulative Amounts of Dupe-only Items in a Resultant Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Sheet 1 goes like this:

[image]

Sheet 2 should be like this:

```
ITEMS   QUANTITIES
APPLE   4
GUAVA   2
```

Sorry for writing the spreadsheet in here, as I'm not allowed to include more than 1 image yet.

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you run into problems?  This seems like a Pivot Table with a filter would give you what you want.

Comment: PivotTable is out of the question as we need a generic simple formula.

Comment: No Filters, no VBA, no Pivot Table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Next time please include your own attempt of solving the problem.

Comment: I know I'm NOT new to the Stack Overflow. Just made a new account, as I lost the last one somewhere. I was just in a hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **ITEMS** being the data in ITEMS column on your `Sheet1`;
- **QUANTITY** being the data in QUANTITY column on your `Sheet1`.

Enter the following formula in Cell `D2` on your `Sheet2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ITEMS,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,ITEMS),0)),"")
```

Please note it is an **array formula** which requires you to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finishing the formula in the formula bar.

Drag it down until there is no more items showing up.

Then you can enter the following formula in Cell `E2` on your `Sheet2` and drag it down:

```
=SUMIF(ITEMS,D2,QUANTITY)
```

[image: Solution]

As you can see from the above screenshot, there may be some empty cells in Column D as I used **IFERROR** to return blank cells if there is no more distinct item. The corresponding quantity will be `0` consequently. You can choose to delete them or hide them on your worksheet.

> By the way I am not sure why `Pivot Table` is out of the picture as it is actually a faster and easier approach than formula and you do not have to worry about the blank cells returned by the formula if the number of unique items is uncertain. All you need to do is to highlight the source data, insert a pivot table, and put the ITEM in `Rows` and QUANTITY in `Values` field.

[image: Pivot Table]

Comment: Man, did anybody ever tell you that you're a frickin' genius! :) Despite of my vague and (probably unfairly) demanding question, your answer was amazingly thorough and so clear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am no genius. The guy who firstly suggested you to use pivot table is more like a genius than me. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Update to also extract unique distinct values:

Enter this formula in cell `A2` of `Sheet2`:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$300)=0),Sheet1!$A$2:$A$300), "")
```

Change 300 to the actual last row of your data and copy that formula down until it returns empty cells.

Then just use a regular `SUMIF` in cell `B2` of `Sheet2`:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!A2:A300, A2, Sheet1!B2:B10)
```

Then, type whatever fruit you're looking for incell `A2` of `Sheet2`. Continue like this in the following rows for all the fruits you need.

Comment: Thanks, but that's a part of what I'm looking for. I need to capture the Fruit Names along with their Added Amounts in Col A and Col B respectively. How to do that?

Comment: Is your dataset large or changing often? Otherwise it would be easiest to just type them in yourself. If yes, I'm sure it's possible to do via worksheet formulas but I'd recommend using VBA.

Comment: DataSet is quite large so manual work is out of the question. Don't want to use VBA as this needs to be simpler. I have managed to get the Fruit names but I'm struggling to write them only once in the new sheet.

Comment: An easy solution would be to copy the dataset to `Sheet2` and then `Remove duplicates`. Then apply the formulas and you're done.

Comment: We need to do it with a Formula.

Comment: I updated my answer, this should be everything you're looking for.

Comment: Dude, you're already getting everything on a silver platter. At least provide some necessary info on what error you are encountering and what you did to get there. Otherwise I won't be able to help at all.

Comment: I think in your first formula you should use `$A$1:A1` instead of `$A$1:A2` which will cause circular reference as you are entering the formula in Cell A2. Other than that your non-array formula works quite well in finding distinct values :)

Comment: Thank you @M.Schalk for your help. Sorry I wasn't very clear.